# Showing that a 2-form on an odd dimensional space is not degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, symplectic-geometry

On an odd-dimensional space $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ with coordinates $x_1...x_n;y_1...y_n;t$ consider the following 2-form:
$$\omega^2=\sum dx_i \land dy_i-\omega^1 \land dt$$
where $\omega^1$ is any 1-form on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$.
How to show that $\omega^2$ is non degenerate?

Comment: Wait. Ofc it's degenerate. It's odd dimensional. Why are you even asking?

Comment: I've just reported the text of the problem, taken from "Mathematical methods of Classical mechanics" by V.I. Arnol'd. I'm confused too!

Comment: @jgon here's the text: https://books.google.it/books?id=UOQlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%22on+an+odd-dimensional%22&source=bl&ots=Qos8WIXFkb&sig=yDpicrZe9mSE7duN2sErSeCoijQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiV0J_rncbeAhUPl4sKHV8HDsMQ6AEwBnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22on%20an%20odd-dimensional%22&f=false

Comment: Well I'm fairly convinced it's degenerate at this point, so idk probably an error? XP

Comment: Or perhaps the author is using the term _nonsingular_ in a non-standard way?

Comment: Ohhhh non-degenerate means something different here

Comment: That's it, an improper use of terminology :-(! Thanks!

Comment: You can adapt the method in my answer to prove that all null vectors for the 2-form are proportional to the one I gave. Hence the 2-form has 1d null space which is the minimum possible. Therefore it is non-degenerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it isn't nondegenerate.

Let $e_{x_i}$, $e_{y_i}$, and $e_t$ denote the standard basis vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{2n+1}$.
Define $v=e_t+\sum_i \omega^1(e_{x_i})e_{y_i}-\omega^1(e_{y_i})e_{x_i}$.
Now we check that $\omega^2(v,e)=0$ for each standard basis vector $e$.

$$\omega^2(v,e_{x_i})=-v_{y_i}+\omega^1(e_{x_i})v_t=-\omega^1(e_{x_i})+\omega^1(e_{x_i})=0$$ for all $i$, similarly evaluating $\omega^2(v,e_{y_i})$ gives
$$\omega^2(v,e_{y_i})=v_{x_i}+\omega^1(e_{y_i})v_t=-\omega^1(e_{y_i})+\omega^1(e_{y_i})=0.$$
Finally, evaluating at $e_t$, we get $\omega^2(v,e_t)=-\omega^1(v)+\omega^1(e_t)v_t$, and expanding $\omega^1(v)$, we get
$$\omega^2(v,e_t)=-\omega^1(e_t)-\sum_i \left(\omega^1(e_{x_i})\omega^1(e_{y_i})-\omega^1(e_{y_i})\omega^1(e_{x_i})\right) +\omega^1(e_t)=0.$$

Hence $v$ exhibits the degeneracy of $\omega^2$. Anyway, it's been a while since I had to do concrete computations with differential forms, so do let me know if I've made any mistakes in here.

**Edit:**

By $v_{x_i}$, $v_{y_i}$, and $v_t$ I mean the real numbers such that
$$v=v_te_t+\sum_i \left(v_{x_i}e_{x_i} + v_{y_i}e_{y_i}\right).$$
By construction of $v$, $v_{x_i}=-\omega^1(e_{y_i})$, $v_{y_i}=\omega^1(e_{x_i})$, and $v_t=1$.

Comment: I know that's "late" and I don't want to bore you @jgon, but what do you mean by $v_y$ and $v_t$ in your answer? Could you write those terms in extended manner?

Comment: I mean the coefficient of the corresponding standard basis vector when we write $v$ in terms of standard basis vectors.

Comment: I have to thank you, but (maybe because I'm not fluent in English) I'm puzzled. If it's not too much to ask, could you write down these terms in extended form?

Comment: @LoScrondo I've provided a longer explanation at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!